# Unable to run local script file with variables through ssh

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I need to run the below script test.sh file to run in remote system.

**variables.txt:**

```
name=stackexchange
```

**test.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./variables.txt
echo $name
```

**Running**:

```
ssh -i "auth.key" user@host 'bash -s' < test.sh
```

But I am getting this error:

```
bash: line 2: ./variables.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error message indicates that the file `variables.txt` does not exist on the remote system. You have to copy it there before running the script that refers to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're telling the shell on the other machine to source the `./variables` file, which is not present in the `pwd` of that shell. Step by step, it looks like this:

1. This command connects via ssh and sends the lines from the local `test.sh`

   ```
   ssh -i "auth.key" user@host 'bash -s' < test.sh
   ```
2. The remote shells gets started by the `ssh` connection, and then gets the following lines:

   - `#!/bin/bash` The interpretation of this line by the remote shell depends on what shell that is. Most shells will treat this line as a comment. If the shell is `sh`, the remote shell will not become `bash`, because the shebang line is only valid in script files, and the scripts need the executable bit set.
   - `source ./variables.txt` Now the remote shell is told to source from the file `variables.txt` in the current working directory. If the file is not there, the shell will throw an error. In your case the shell is Bash, and the error is:

     ```
     bash: line 2: ./variables.txt: No such file or directory
     ```
   - `echo $name` Because `$name` is empty, there's only an empty line printed in the terminal.

To confirm this yourself, place a file `variables.txt` in the remote home directory with a different line to source, say:

```
name=remotehost
```

And run your test script like before.

Answer (score 1):

Programs running on the remote machine see the files on the remote machine, not the files on the machine where you ran `ssh` from. You're telling SSH to copy the content of `test.sh` to the remote machine and pass it as input to `bash` there, so you have no problem running `test.sh`. But when the script (which bash receives on standard input) tries to read `variables.txt`, it looks for it on the machine that it's executing on (it's not as if it had a choice), and doesn't find it.

If your script isn't too complex and there aren't nested inclusions then you could do a text replacement to inline the content of the script. Note that this is fragile — it only works if `source ./variables.txt` appears directly in the script, not if it involves complex quoting, variables, `eval`, etc. For simplicity I'll assume that the `source` command is alone on its line. More complex transformations would be possible to cope with more complex scenarios.

```
<test.sh sed '/^[ \t]*source variables\.txt[ \t]*$/ {
  d
  r variables.txt
}' | ssh -i "auth.key" user@host 'bash -s'
```